# Unable to position Data labels on a top of bars SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

For some reason I am unable to display data labels for my chart on a top of bars. 
I need percentage for my orange bar on a top.
What I do:
go to data label properties and set `Position-top`, but it doesnt work.

Here is my chart in design view:

[image]

Here is in preview mode:

[image]

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/position-labels-in-a-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs  It seems to indicate you need to change the BarLabelStyle property

Comment: I did look at it. But there is no exactly `BarLabelStyle ` in SSRS 2012